# compiler gives error when i run this angular project. deleted and reinstalled node modules and degrade the node version but didnt work

Tags: node.js, angular

this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
at processResource (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
at runLoaders (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
at NormalModule.build (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
at Compilation.buildModule (D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
at D:\LMS H\CMS-Frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Deleted node modules and installed them again and degraded the node version too stil the same error presists